# An inequality concerning the measure of a difference of measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \sum, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a
sequence of measurable sets with $\mu(A_n)\longrightarrow 0$ as $n\longrightarrow\infty$.
For each integer $n$ let us define $B_n:=A_n-\cup_{m=n+1}^{\infty}A_m$. Now, 
if the $A_n$'s are (mutually) disjoint, then clearly $\mu(A_n)=\mu(B_n)\leq\mu(\cup_{m=n}^{\infty}B_m)$.

But, if we suppose that the $A_n$'s are not necessarily disjoint, how to show that, for each integer $n$, $\mu(A_n)\leq\mu(\cup_{m=n}^{\infty}B_m)$? (Note that the sets $B_n$'s are (mutually) disjoint.)

Anybody could help me to show this inequality? Thanks a lot in advance.

(Note that here for two sets $A$ and $B$, $A-B$ means $A-B=\{x: \ x\in A \ \text{and} \ x\in \!\!\!\!\!/ B\}$.)

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: It was needed to solve a problem in the Folland's Real Analysis Book, saying that, for $0<p<q<\infty$,  $L^p$ is not a subset of $L^q$ iff $X$ contains sets of arbitrarily small positive measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true. Consider the interval $[0,1)$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure. Let $A_1=[0,1)$. Now divide this interval into two half-open intervals of equal length, let $A_2$ be the first such piece and $A_3$ the second. Then divide the interval into four such half-open intervals, let $A_4$ be the leftmost of those and continue this way. Then $\lim_n \mu(A_n)=0$, so the assumptions hold. But for every $k$, we have $\bigcup_{m=k}^\infty A_m=[0,1)$. It follows that each $B_n$ is empty with measure zero and so is their union. But all $A_n$ have positive measure.

Comment: Why for each $k$, $\cup_{m=k}^\infty A_m=[0,1)$ ? Am I missing something? I think, at least, the disjoints of the $A_n$'s must be enough to have $\mu(A_n)=\mu(B_n)$, isn't it?

Comment: No matter how large the index $n$, there will always be some number $k$ such that a partition of $[0,1)$ into $2^k$ pieces occur among the sets in the sequence after $n$.Their union is $[0,1)$. I have no idea what you mean by "disjoints".

Comment: Sorry, in my first comment, I meant ''disjointness".

Comment: Your question stated that the answer is clearly yes when the sets are disjointed and inquired what would happen if they are not. In this answer, they are not disjoint and the result does not hold.